# Mitigating nausea when generating artificial gravity by centrifuge

Tags: health, humans, artificial-gravity

When utilizing "artificial gravity" generated through a rotating structure using centripetal force, i.e. a centrifuge, is there a minimum diameter or some other attribute that causes or helps alleviate any kind of nausea or motion sickness in humans?

Comment: The soviet union did some ground experiments of this using centrifuges, you may want to research that.

Comment: If it helps, I discuss a bit those Soviet centrifuge experiments that @GdD mentions in [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/5626/49) to [Adapting to Increased Gravity on Alien Planets](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/5624/49). Including effects on cosmonauts that such a system had.

Comment: Other "attributes": There are pills against nausea. Astronaut selection would prevent it since some never have any problem with it. Rotation should be similar to the sinodal ride on the waves at sea.

Comment: partially related to [my question](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/7994/would-a-rotating-spacecraft-disorient-those-looking-out-of-it) (which is unanswered if you want to take a whack at it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is about a so called 'comfort zone'. In fact it is not radius but a ratio of radius and angular velocity. Nausea or motion sickness is caused mostly by Coriolis acceleration which makes 'artificial gravity' different form nearly homogeneous earth gravity.

There is a real expert on topic [Theodore W. Hall](http://www.twhall.com/). 
Among a lot of staff about artificial gravity he published an

[online calculator](http://www.artificial-gravity.com/sw/SpinCalc/SpinCalc.htm)

which may provides the best answer of the question.

[image: comfort zone of artificial gravity]

Direct answer if your question is R<12 meters or <60 m for 1 g.

By the way, it is what the quality Sci-Fi movies lake 'Odyssey 2001' depicted. Arthur Clark and Stanley Kubrick have had some info on topic.

Comment: Shouldn't the less-than signs be greater-than, e.g., R>12 meters?

Comment: @BenCrowell I second Ben Crowell's comment. Val, you have a *serious* typo, I think.

Answer (score 7):

*Is* there a minimum diameter?  Yes.  Every study I've come across agrees on that.

What is that minimum diameter?  As I found [while answering this question over on WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/what-minimal-radius-is-needed-for-rotation-to-simulate-gravitation-without-avers/2462#2462), there's quite a bit of disagreement there.  Allowable minimum diameters vary from as high as [180 km](http://www.spacefuture.com/archive/inhabiting_artificial_gravity.shtml) to as low as [8 meters](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2002ESASP.501..151H).

Comment: very good link and very interesting, thank you.